# How can i get default template/layout for whole project in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, layout, view

Can anyone tell me how I can implement a default template/layout for my whole project in codeigniter?

One way I found is [Templating with Code Igniter (CI Forums)](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/88664/)

Is there any other way? Can anyone post complete example code?

Comment: A suggestion, Try it yourself, and then post any issues, no one here likes to post entire code blocks if there has been no attempt by the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make one layout view. Some thing like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My awesome site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?= $this->load->view('shared/header') ?>
    <?= $this->load->view($partial) ?>
    <?= $this->load->view('shared/footer') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in your controller do this:

```
$this->data['partial'] = 'pages/index';
$this->load->view('layout/layout', $this->data);
```

If you have a MY_Controller file you can create a method there:

```
function load_view($partial)
{
  $this->data['partial'] = $partial;
  $this->load->view('layout/layout', $this->data);
}
```

Then in controllers that inherit from MY_Controller you can use:

```
$this->load_view('pages/index'); // pages/index will be loaded in the layout
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways I know of one of them is to create a header and footer view for your site / project.

```
application/views/template/header.php
application/views/template/footer.php
```

Then you have your other pages arranged how you would like.

```
application/views/users/login.php
```

In your controller you would do something like this

```
<?php
    class Blah extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('template/header');
            $this->load->view('users/login');
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
        }
    }
```

There is also a useful little template library I stumbled across, that makes this even simpler. I don't find it quite as flexible as typing out the other way of doing it though.

http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_template

EDIT::
I should of given some example code for the template so here you go

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Lovely Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Check This Out!!1!</h1>
        <div class="container">
```

footer.php

```
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to load headers and footers in the controller. You'll be repeating yourself over and over. It'd better to create a layout view file and load headers/footers in there. Then you only have to do it once.

Comment: Yes the link I offered does exactly the same as your suggestion. Too many ways to skin a cat :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always load a view withing other view and implement what you want.

Other better way is to use a template engine which supports template inheritance like

- [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#template-inheritance)
- [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/inheritance)
- [Dwoo](http://wiki.dwoo.org/index.php/TemplateInheritance)

Using them in CodeIgniter is fairly easy as there are many implementations of the libraries for CI.